# Understanding the Unix dup2 system call?

Tags: c, unix, process, pipe

I'm playing around with the [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) function to try and get a better grasp of it.

From looking at the manual, it takes two parameters. First is the existing file descriptor and second parameter is the copied file descriptor.

I decided to try and redirect stdout to my write end of the pipe.

Judging by the manual I thought the code should be...

```
 if ((dup2(STDOUT_FILENO, fd[1])) <= 0)
    {
       printf("error on dup \n");
    }

 write(STDOUT_FILENO, "Hi \n", 5);
```

As stdout would now be duplicated to fd[1]. Therefore if we wrote to stdout we should be writing to write end of pipe. However this still prints to screen. So I assumed it should be fd[1] followed by stdout. So does that mean stdout is now a copy of fd[1] and that's why it's working.

Lastly if I wanted to write back to screen....how would I do this in same process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prototype for dup2 is: **int dup2(int oldfd, int newfd);**

So your cope:

```
dup2(STDOUT_FILENO, fd[1])
```

copies the *stream* associated with STDOUT_FILENO (which normally will be 1) to the decriptor in fd[1]. Let's assume you have put the descriptor value 4 in fd[1], then at the end, both 1 and 4 will both point to the "standard output stream" which is usually the terminal tty/pty.

After the call (if successful), fd[1] no longer refers to a pipe. Sounds like you are confusing dup/dup2 functionality with pipe. `pipe()` creates a descriptor pair with a read and write end. If you then fork, you can connect two processes with the pipe, and after that, a child process with a pipe can dup its pipe to STDIN_FILENO or STDOUT_FILENO such that standard library routines will read/write from those descriptors thinking they are reading/writing to the terminal.

The only thing that makes 0, 1, 2 special are that they are initially opened to a terminal, and that library routines refer to them by number (or macro SDTIN_FILENO, etc.) The dup calls basically increment the reference count for a particular descriptor and link the underlying descriptor slot to the original slot.

Sounds like what you want to do is pass fd[1] in the first argument, and dup it to STDOUT_FILENO in order to connect your pipe to a standard stream.